# Scraping a website with data that's dynamically generated

Tags: python, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape the match table from this link: https://www.kayak-polo.info/kpmatchs.php?lang=en&event=0&Saison=2022&Group=CM&Compet=*&J=*&Round=*&Css=&navGroup=1

Unfortunately the data is dynamically generated and I cannot seem to figure out a way to get it to work.

It seems like the data is generated dynamically based on a selection you make up here:
[image: image for selecting]

I tried looking at the network tab and it eventually got me to datatables.net. I however can't seem to figure out a way to get the data from that website. It seems to make a post request with certain headers, but it's unfortunately not very clear to me what that does.

There is no api call

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The desired table data isn't populated by JavaScript meaing data is in static `HTML DOM` and you can grab the table data using pandas DataFrame.

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
headers = {'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0'}
url = 'https://www.kayak-polo.info/kpmatchs.php?lang=en&event=0&Saison=2022&Group=CM&Compet=*&J=*&Round=*&Css=&navGroup=1'
req= requests.get(url,headers=headers).text
df = pd.read_html(req)[0]
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
          #             Date  ...                     Referee 2                                              Games
    0    501  2022-08-1610:20  ...             THOMAS Mark (GBR)  08-16 10:20 - Pitch 1  Group UW  ITA U21 Women...     
    1    503  2022-08-1610:20  ...           BELISLE Ricky (AUS)  08-16 10:20 - Pitch 3  Group UW  ESP U21 Women...     
    2    504  2022-08-1610:20  ...  ANDZIAK-GINTER Marzena (POL)  08-16 10:20 - Pitch 4  Group UW  NED U21 Women...     
    3    508  2022-08-1613:00  ...           BELISLE Ricky (AUS)  08-16 13:00 - Pitch 4  Group UW  ITA U21 Women...     
    4    506  2022-08-1813:15  ...           BELISLE Ricky (AUS)  08-18 13:15 - Pitch 2  Group UW  POL U21 Women...     
    ..   ...              ...  ...                           ...                                                ...     
    280  464  2022-08-1914:25  ...            WOLFF Sandra (GER)  08-19 14:25 - Pitch 4  Classifying 13-16  CZE ...     
    281  545  2022-08-2016:00  ...                           NaN    08-20 16:00 - Pitch 5th place  GBR U21 Women  -     
    282  195  2022-08-2112:05  ...                           NaN  08-21 12:05 - Pitch 5  21th place  UKR Men  Aw...     
    283  546  2022-08-2016:00  ...                           NaN    08-20 16:00 - Pitch 8th place  ITA U21 Women  -     
    284    #             Date  ...                     Referee 2                                                NaN     
    

[285 rows x 11 columns]
```